# Is there a function in R to reduce a big confusion matrix to a 2x2 positive-negative level confusion matrix in R?

Tags: r, confusion-matrix

Say we have the following confusion matrix:

```
a <- round(matrix(runif(100,1,100), nrow=10),0)
colnames(a) <- LETTERS[1:10]
rownames(a) <- LETTERS[1:10]
a
    A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J
A  42 35  1  9 83 26  4 21 82  4
B 100 53 28 33 52 62 73 85 53 49
C  26 12 33 63 57  4 46 61 21 55
D  51 89 59 45  1 15 57 76 85 84
E   9 95 26 80 15 71 87 57 38 73
F  82  5  5 29 87  7 56 28 31 56
G  39 50 12 58  9 63 74 74 77  8
H  80 23 71  5 25 94 63 55 74 15
I  21 86 94 20 98 10 32 35 84 69
J  95 54 32 73 58 97 40 52 57 11
```

Considering that columns are actual values and rows predicted values, is there a function that can use this matrix to output a 2 x 2 (TP/TN/FP/FN) confusion matrix where, for example, A would be the positive level and the rest of the letters would form the negative level?  Thanks!

Comment: Do you know your expected values given this matrix?

Comment: This is an example that would show true values as columns and predicted values as rows, not sure what expected means here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of one that already exists, but perhaps this is a technique.

As much to simplify as to show what's being used where, I'll create a same-dim matrix that shows what type is found where:

```r
types <- a          # simple way to copy dims and dimnames
types[] <- "TN"     # default value for most cells
types[,"A"] <- "FP" 
types["A",] <- "FN"
types["A","A"] <- "TP"
types
#   A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H    I    J   
# A "TP" "FN" "FN" "FN" "FN" "FN" "FN" "FN" "FN" "FN"
# B "FP" "TN" "TN" "TN" "TN" "TN" "TN" "TN" "TN" "TN"
# C "FP" "TN" "TN" "TN" "TN" "TN" "TN" "TN" "TN" "TN"
# D "FP" "TN" "TN" "TN" "TN" "TN" "TN" "TN" "TN" "TN"
# E "FP" "TN" "TN" "TN" "TN" "TN" "TN" "TN" "TN" "TN"
# F "FP" "TN" "TN" "TN" "TN" "TN" "TN" "TN" "TN" "TN"
# G "FP" "TN" "TN" "TN" "TN" "TN" "TN" "TN" "TN" "TN"
# H "FP" "TN" "TN" "TN" "TN" "TN" "TN" "TN" "TN" "TN"
# I "FP" "TN" "TN" "TN" "TN" "TN" "TN" "TN" "TN" "TN"
# J "FP" "TN" "TN" "TN" "TN" "TN" "TN" "TN" "TN" "TN"
```

How we use this:

```r
a[which(types == "FN", arr.ind = TRUE)]
# [1] 46 90 74 39 34 68  5 59 67
sum(a[which(types == "FN", arr.ind = TRUE)])
# [1] 482
a[which(types == "FP", arr.ind = TRUE)]
# [1] 94 29 83 65 52 74 14 66 71
sum(a[which(types == "FP", arr.ind = TRUE)])
# [1] 548
```

Full matrix:

```r
outer(setNames(nm = c("T", "F")), setNames(nm = c("P", "N")),
      Vectorize(function(tf, pn) sum(a[which(types == paste0(tf, pn))]),
                vectorize.args = c("tf", "pn")))
#     P    N
# T  92 4172
# F 548  482
```

or if you want just the named-counts:

```r
sapply(unique(c(types)),
       function(typ) sum(a[which(types == typ)]))
#   TP   FP   FN   TN 
#   92  548  482 4172
```

---

My random data:

```r
set.seed(42)
a <- round(matrix(runif(100,1,100), nrow=10),0)
colnames(a) <- LETTERS[1:10]
rownames(a) <- LETTERS[1:10]
a
#    A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J
# A 92 46 90 74 39 34 68  5 59 67
# B 94 72 15 81 44 35 98 15 17  1
# C 29 94 99 39  5 40 76 22 37 22
# D 83 26 95 69 97 79 57 48 65 93
# E 65 47  9  1 44  5 85 21 78 93
# F 52 94 52 83 96 75 20 72 57 74
# G 74 98 40  2 89 68 28  2 24 34
# H 14 13 91 22 64 18 83 38 10 52
# I 66 48 45 91 97 27 70 52  9 75
# J 71 56 84 62 62 52 25  1 31 62
```

Comment: Thanks! this is a way to do it, but would like to wait and see if something a bit more straightforward shows up before accepting the answer

Comment: It doesn't look like this is getting the attention you want it to (in order to compete the answer). If you still think you want competing answers, you might need to add a bounty.